# Where does job.setOutputKeyClass and job.setOutputReduceClass refers to?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I thought that they refer to the Reducer but in my program I have

`public static class MyMapper extends 
            Mapper< LongWritable, Text, Text, Text >`

and

`public static class MyReducer extends 
            Reducer< Text, Text, NullWritable, Text >`

so if I have

`job.setOutputKeyClass( NullWritable.class );`

`job.setOutputValueClass( Text.class );`

I get the following Exception

`Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`

but if I have

`job.setOutputKeyClass( Text.class );`

there is no problem.

Is there sth wrong with my code or this happens because of NullWritable or sth else?

Also do I have to use `job.setInputFormatClass` and `job.setOutputFormatClass`? Because my programs runs correctly without them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Calling `job.setOutputKeyClass( NullWritable.class );` will set the types expected as output from both the map and reduce phases.

If your Mapper emits different types than the Reducer, you can set the types emitted by the mapper with the `JobConf`'s `setMapOutputKeyClass()` and `setMapOutputValueClass()` methods. These implicitly set the input types expected by the Reducer.

(source: [Yahoo Developer Tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html))

Regarding your second question, the default `InputFormat` is the `TextInputFormat`. This treats each line of each input file as a separate record, and performs no parsing. You can call these methods if you need to process your input in a different format, here are some examples:

```
InputFormat             | Description                                      | Key                                      | Value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TextInputFormat         | Default format; reads lines of text files        | The byte offset of the line              | The line contents
KeyValueInputFormat     | Parses lines into key, val pairs                 | Everything up to the first tab character | The remainder of the line
SequenceFileInputFormat | A Hadoop-specific high-performance binary format | user-defined                             | user-defined
```

The default instance of `OutputFormat` is `TextOutputFormat`, which writes (key, value) pairs on individual lines of a text file. Some examples below:

```
OutputFormat             | Description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TextOutputFormat         | Default; writes lines in "key \t value" form
SequenceFileOutputFormat | Writes binary files suitable for reading into subsequent MapReduce jobs
NullOutputFormat         | Disregards its inputs
```

(source: [Other Yahoo Developer Tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html))

Comment: Oh you're right,I didn't know about the two methods that you mentioned.Adding them my program runs.Of course I use Job not JobConf but the methods exists as well.Thank you very much!Could you tell me sth about the last part of my question?

Comment: @nik686 I added the answer to the last part of your question above.

Comment: So the default is TextInputFormat and TextOutputFormat that's why my program runs.Thank you very much!

Comment: @CharlesMenguy.
Am I understanding this right?

**If your Mapper emits different types than the Reducer, you can set the types emitted by the mapper with the JobConf's setMapOutputKeyClass() and setMapOutputValueClass() methods**. 

I see this error even when my Mapper and Reducer outputs match.   
`Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`

It seems to be directly correlating with the InputFormat classes, e.g. to match TextInputFormatClass's expectation of LongWritable key and Text output.